# How to reuse dependency versions in subprojects for Kotlin DSL?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, kotlin-dsl

I have a multi module Gradle project with Kotlin DSL as build file. Inside of the root `build.gradle.kts` there is `dependencies` section for root and `subprojects` with its own `dependencies`. I would like to create a variable that can keep version of some dependency and be used in all modules in `build.gradle.kts`.

Root `build.gradle.kts` looks like:

```kotlin
buildscript {
// ...
}
plugins {
// ...
}
subprojects {
// repositories, plugins, tasks, etc.

dependencies {
   implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.4")
}
```

Submodule `common-module/build.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
dependencies {
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-csv:2.10.4")
}
```

I would like to declare a variable and assign the version for these dependencies as a value and only reuse it on modules. Some thing like     `implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-csv:${jacksonVersion}")`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most modern, type-safe solution of this problem is using [version catalogs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html).

1. Update Gradle to at least 7.5.1.
2. `gradle/libs.versions.toml`:

```
[versions]
jackson = "2.12.5"

[libraries]
jackson-databind = { module = "com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-databind", version.ref = "jackson" }
jackson-dataformat-csv = { module = "com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-csv", version.ref = "jackson" }
```

3. Add dependencies like `implementation(libs.jackson.dataformat.csv)` in all the subprojects.